# Is it a good practice to accessing button id in a loop?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am accessing button in loop like following.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int clickedButtonId=v.getId();
    for(int buttonIndex=1;buttonIndex<=MAX_BUTTON;buttonIndex++) {
        int buttonId = getResources().getIdentifier("button" + buttonIndex, "id", getPackageName());
        if(clickedButtonId==buttonId){
            showToast(buttonIndex);
            openLink(LIKS[buttonIndex-1]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it good prctice or bad ?

Comment: if your layout is not heavy and also the speed of run time is not important , i think there is no problem to use this code.

Comment: Please don't add tag names, like Android, to questions titles(that's what the tags at the bottom are for). You should avoid using getIdentifier() in loops as it has some performances issues(but it all depends on how many iterations there are and how often you do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accesing only button's id in a UI thread in a loop is not a big deal but it can heavily slow down you UI activity screen if you perform heavy processing on the button. I suggest using an AsyncTask for performing such kind of processing..

For more details, refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html